# Unable to render a SVG graph from a dot when adding multi-edges using graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

Im trying to render my dot file using: grv.render('neato', 'svg', 'graph.dot').

The dot file is at the bottom of the question.(quite large, 1500+ lines).

Web apps like Magjac's http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/, are able to render it no problem.

My heroku app running this code is running python 3.9, graphviz python module 0.2 and graphviz 2.43.

I've tried multiple esep, and sep configurations.
Splines being turned off works so error seems to come from the routing of multi-edges because this issue only occurs when my graph has them.

Error reads the same as it does with graphs that work fine, just node size too large warnings:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '[PosixPath('dot'), '-Kdot', '-Tsvg', '-O', 'graphe.dot']' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>. [stderr: b"Warning: node 'Apollon', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Ath\xc3\xa9na', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'H\xc3\xa9lios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Th\xc3\xa9os / Th\xc3\xa9a', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Tych\xc3\xa9', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Autre', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Pythios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Ar\xc3\xa8s', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Areios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Tauropole', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Sipyl\xc3\xaanos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Kisaloudenos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Panda', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Aphrodite', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Stratonikis', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Patr\xc3\xb4os', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Akraios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Capitolin', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Roma', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Pluton', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Cor\xc3\xa9', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'S\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8n\xc3\xa8', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Ascl\xc3\xa9pios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Anthropos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Enfant', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Fleuve', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Moi / Nous', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'M\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8s', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'H\xc3\xa9racl\xc3\xa8s', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Dionysos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Megas', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Briseus', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Devant-la-ville', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'D\xc3\xa9m\xc3\xa9ter', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Thesmophoros', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Hoplophylax', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'N\xc3\xa9m\xc3\xa9sis', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Daim\xc3\xb4n', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Ouranios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Hypsistos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Arch\xc3\xa9g\xc3\xa8te', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Nik\xc3\xa8', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Athanatos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Makar', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Cypris', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Qui (est) sous terre', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Smyrna\xc3\xafkos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Agathos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Polis', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Brillant', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Thessalonicien', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Chryseos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Art\xc3\xa9mis', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Sebastos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Leucophry\xc3\xa8ne', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Ep\xc3\xaakoos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Kallinikos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'M\xc3\xa9decin', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Kyrios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Sarapis', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Hermos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Moire', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'P\xc3\xa9an', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Anax', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Bacchus', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Kydalimos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Redoutable', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Had\xc3\xa8s', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Gardien-des-portes', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Eaque', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Sombre', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Nychios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Alampetos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'P\xc3\xa8re', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Toi / Vous', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Phoibos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Fils', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Hypnodot\xc3\xaas', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Nuit', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Hekaergos', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Bromios', graph '%3' size too small for label\nWarning: node 'Asrigeneia', graph '%3' size too small for label\n"]
```

And traceback:

```
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/appuser/streamlit_app.py", line 502, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/appuser/streamlit_app.py", line 377, in main
    gr = graph_create(nodes, edges, node_sep, bg_color, node_list, 0, False, debug)
File "/home/appuser/streamlit_app.py", line 255, in graph_create
    grv.render('dot', 'svg', 'graphe.dot')
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/backend/rendering.py", line 324, in render
    execute.run_check(cmd,
File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz/backend/execute.py", line 93, in run_check
    raise CalledProcessError(*e.args)
```

The Dot file didnt fit in the stackoverflow character limit.

Here is a pastebin of it: https://pastebin.com/gpm9S0y9

Comment: 2.43.0 is rather old (several years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.43.0 is rather old (several years).  If you install a new version of Graphviz (4.0) it works fine.  Unfortunately, "installing a newer version" can take some real work.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, will try to work towards that goal, not very knowledgeable in that domain but cant hurts to try